# Python: py2app "ImportError: dlopen(): Library not loaded"

Tags: python, macos, numpy, importerror, py2app

I've written a python script that does some work with numpy and scikit's audiolab. I want to create a standalone app using py2app but I keep getting the same error no matter which OS X computer I test it on.

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/transfer15/Desktop/app/dist/PCMAlign/app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/numpy/linalg/lapack_lite.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libmkl_intel_lp64.dylib

Referenced from: /Users/transfer15/Desktop/app/dist/PCMAlign/app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/numpy/linalg/lapack_lite.so

Reason: image not found
```

This is somewhat strange to me because if I follow the filepath I can see `lapack_lite.so` in the correct folder.

Is there any fix for this? Or, is there any way to exclude this library, since I'm not using linear algebra (pretty much just using the numpy arrays) so as to avoid this error?

Thanks!

Comment: Could it be a version mismatch? Can you try it with the current dev version of numpy?

Comment: is there any way for me to tell if there's a version mismatch? I've never used numpy before this project and installing it what somewhat of a terror for me. How can I try it with the current dev version?

Comment: you can clone it from here: git://github.com/numpy/numpy.git and run "setup.py install".

Answer (score 0):

Having encountered the same problem recently (Python 2.7, trying to import numpy version 1.11), downgrading the version of numpy cleared up the error.

If you used pip to install numpy, you can downgrade with: `pip install 'numpy<1.7'`. It is possible that a higher version may work out for you.